# How are Master Encryption Keys being stored?

Tags: security, encryption

What storage methods does Salesforce use to store [Master Encryption Keys](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_keys_using_master.htm&language=th)? For example, are the master keys stored in some type of secure key store? If so, what methods does it use to ensure the keys are secured?

To clarify, I am looking for information on how the actual encryption keys themselves are being securely being stored, not methods on storing information in Salesforce using encrypted fields. The difference is the Master Encryption Keys are used to encrypt the information in the encrypted fields. The Master Encryption Keys can be managed by going to:

> Setup > Security Controls > Certificate and Key Management

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks .I think i misunderstood the whole thing .Deleted my answer .Thank you for headsup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reached out to Salesforce support. As it turns out, the answer to this question is available, but the information is confidential.

As a Salesforce customer under NDA, you may open a case with Salesforce support and they may provide you with the answer as well.